# Couldn't run my test using Microsoft Test Manager

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, mstest, microsoft-test-manager, mt

When I'm running the test in Microsoft Test Manager I get an error: The build directory of the test run either does not exist or access permission is required.

What does it mean? Where can I check build directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are running **automated** tests.

If you are running automated test in *Microsoft Test Manageg* (MTM) you have *Test Case(s)* automated by your test implementation.
So *MTM* need to know where is the drop location of the build building your tests.

That means you have to:

1. Create a *Build definition* that build the code implementing your tests.
2. Configure *MTM* to use the drop location of this build definition.

You can check which build *MTM* is currently using here:

[image]

(I suppose you will have "*undefined*" standing there.)

You can configure which build is to use here:

[image]

Just check here how to configure your *Test Plan* which build to use when running tests: [Creating and Defining a Test Plan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd286583%28VS.110%29.aspx#CreatePlan)

Additionally I would highly recommend you this **free** e-book: [Testing for Continuous Delivery with Visual Studio 2012](http://msmvps.com/blogs/molausson/archive/2012/10/21/testing-for-continuous-delivery-with-visual-studio-2012.aspx)