# Automated Tests in Microsoft Test Manager (build directory of the test run either does not exist or access permission is required)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing, microsoft-test-manager

I'm trying to run automated test cases in Microsoft Test Manager. I'm so close, but I keep getting an error. I'm running my tests in MTM and I get the following error:

The build directory of the test run either does not exist or access permission is required.

I'm so lost. Where the heck is the build directory of the test run located? Where is the build drop location?

I went to Plan --> Properties --> and checked that my "Build in use" is the latest one and isn't left blank.

Comment: Upvoted, because I can't stand it when people downvote and don't comment as to why.

Answer (score -1):

> In Microsoft Test and Lab Manager, the above error message is observed during the execution of an automated test run on a test controller. It can occur in either of the following conditions.
>
> 1. The account under which test controller is running does not have read permission on the build directory. (The build directory is same as the drop location of build associated with this test run.)
> 2. The build directory itself does not exist.
>
> So to come out of this error, ensure that build directory exists and test controller service account has read permission on it.

[MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aseemb/archive/2009/11/25/error-starting-the-test-run-build-directory-of-the-test-run-is-not-specified-or-does-not-exist.aspx)

I hope this helps.

Also, there is this post on StackOverflow about a similar issue [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033217/couldnt-run-my-test-using-microsoft-test-manager)

Comment: I know I saw this. But I don't know where to access this information. Where is the build directory to check?

Comment: The build directory is where ever your builders normally drop your builds.

Comment: Okay, I found the location. Now what? Do I just right-click the folder --> "Share With" and then add the machine/account I'm using? I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: If the account has permissions to access that share there could be another issue. Please double check that the account has the correct permissions (read) and then open the test agent and test controller  log files to see if there are any other issues that could be causing this.

[How to enable logging on a test agent](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aseemb/archive/2010/03/07/how-to-enable-test-agent-logs.aspx)

Comment: Okay, I think I may have another issue. When I'm setting up my environments, does the Test Agent have to be explicitly installed on the machine/role? In other words, do I need to have "Test Agent Configuration Tool" ready on the machine/role that I'm adding to my lab environment? I'm confused because it said that the Lab environment will automatically do that for me and not to create it manually.

Comment: I have found that the auto configuration does not always work 100%. I install the test agent and then just add it to the environment from the list of agents that test manager detects.

Comment: I'm going to try and re-do everything on another machine. Just for the record, can the Microsoft Test Manager be on a DIFFERENT computer domain than where the build drop folder and Team Foundation Server is located?

Comment: As long as it has access and rights to both you should be ok. Your test agent will have to be set up differently if it is on a different domain than your controller.